# Load tableview inside footerview of collectionview swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I'm trying to reuse view from another viewcontroller (which contains tableview) to the below of collectionview.

Currently I'm doing like.

Added one footerview and loaded the view to it. I'm trouble in knowing when the tableview content size is loaded fully. So that I can assign same to height of footer view. Is there any delegate for knowing the same?  Or any other way to achieve this feature

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of an awkward work around but assuming you've already fetched your data and stored it in an array, as well as you know what the height of one cell would be, you can then maybe try something like this:

***After passing the array into the second view controllers array***

```
var yourData: [YourObject] = []

if self.yourData.count > 0 {
    let count = self.yourData.count
    let singleCellSize: CGFloat = 200

    self.footerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: singleCellSize * count) /* MULTIPLY THE HEIGHT BY THE NUMBER OF CELLS */
}
```

Comment: Good answer. Actually this is not scenario. the data is known at runtime